# Discuss how "GIS Web Service" package can be used in python to access GIS information

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

I want brief information about how python GIS web service package is used for accessing GIS information with one example.I am new to python , but i want this for my further projects.

Comment: 1) What kind of "python GIS web service package" are you talking about? 2) What exact are you trying to do? 3) Are you trying to do web/internet GIS or web-based mapping?

Answer (score 1):

First let me explain what the concept of GIS is? Over the years, the concept of GIS has experienced continues changes, from Geographical Information System (**GISystem**) to Geographical Information Science (**GIScience**), and then the development of Geographical Information Services (**GIServices**).

- GISystem: Talks about GIS as a **tool** or **system** for solving geospatial related problems. Its components include: Hardware, Software, Data, Users, Procedure/Methods and Network.
- GIScience: Talks about GIS as a scientific **discipline** of study in the academia. The major contributing disciplines are: Computer science, Mathematics/Statistics, Geomatics (Land Surveying, Photogrametry, Remote Sensing, Geodesy, GPS), Geography and Cartography.
- GIServices: Talks about GIS as a **Service** or an **Overhaul** or a **Provision** for delivering of geospatial information often via the web. Some examples are: MapQuest, Google maps, Bing Maps, Yahoo Maps, Apple Maps, Yandex Maps, OpenStreetMap and WikiMapia Maps.

I have strong feelings that your question is inclined toward "GIServices".

**Python** is an open source interpreted programming language used in many GIS programs. Python is a dynamic and strongly typed general purpose programming language. It has an extensive standard library and a community-run index of third-party packages for GIS software check: [GIS PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=GIS).

Python's use in GIS goes back to about 2000 with the development of Python bindings for [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) and [AVPython](http://avpython.sourceforge.net/).

Here is the link between the two (Python + GIS web Services)...

**Python and GIServices**

There several **python** packages/libraries for **GIS web services** and a large variety of useful GIS-related add-ons. Some notable once include: Folium, GeoDjango, MapFish, ArcPy, PyQGIS etc.

All of these packages can be used for accessing GIS information. An example of using folium package can be found on [the official website](https://web.archive.org/web/20210928161548/https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/tree/master/examples/).

Further reading:

1. [GIS Programming with Python and QGIS software](https://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com/2016/07/GIS-Programming-with-Python-and-QGIS-Part-1.html)
2. [Introduction to: GISystem, GIScience, and GIService](https://map.sdsu.edu/geoagent/gis_intro.htm)